# I'm Not able to assign ArrayList returned by OnPostExecute method of AysncTask in main activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to return an `ArrayList` from `onPostExecute` method of `AsyncTask` in Main Activity. I'm assigning returned ArrayList to the searchedText ArrayList of main activity. I'm not able to get elements of searchedText ArrayList in `btnSearch` `onClickListener`. Please let me know what is wrong in the code.

```
package com.example.dharak029.hw3_group09;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText textIn;
    ImageButton buttonAdd;
    LinearLayout container;
    ArrayList<String> wordList;
    byte[] buffer;
    String text;
    ArrayList<String> searchText;
    ArrayList<String> searchedText;
    int keywordCount=0;

    void setResult(ArrayList<String> searchedText){
        this.searchedText = searchedText;
        Log.d("result",""+searchedText.size());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textIn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textin);
        buttonAdd = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add);
        container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        searchText = new ArrayList<String>();


        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("textfile.txt");
            int size = is.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            text = new String(buffer);

            int startIndex = 0;

            for(int i=0;i<text.length()/30;i++){
                searchText.add(text.substring(startIndex,startIndex+30));
                startIndex = startIndex+30;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }




        findViewById(R.id.btnSearch).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for(String word: wordList){
                  new DoWork(MainActivity.this).execute(word);
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WordsFound.class);
                intent.putExtra("searchResults",searchedText);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (keywordCount <= 20) {
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                            (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                    final TextView textOut = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);
                    textOut.setText(textIn.getText().toString());
                    wordList.add(textIn.getText().toString());
                    ImageButton buttonRemove = (ImageButton) addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);

                    final View.OnClickListener thisListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                            wordList.remove(textOut.getText().toString());

                            listAllAddView();
                            keywordCount--;
                        }
                    };

                    buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(thisListener);
                    container.addView(addView);

                    listAllAddView();
                    keywordCount++;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void listAllAddView(){
        int childCount = container.getChildCount();
        for(int i=0; i<childCount; i++){
            View thisChild = container.getChildAt(i);
        }
    }


    class DoWork extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,ArrayList<String>>{

        ArrayList<String> searchResult = new ArrayList<String>();
        ProgressBar progress;
        MainActivity activity;

        public DoWork(MainActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
            for(int i=0;i<searchText.size();i++){
                String text = searchText.get(i);
                if(text.contains(params[0]))
                    searchResult.add(text);
            }
            Log.d("demo",""+searchResult.size());
            return searchResult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            activity.setResult(aVoid);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you are using async task in for loop and setting result on post execute. It will just assign last executed result in setResult().

Comment: Yes. That's right. But after last iteration also I'm not able to get any elements in searchedText under on click listener event. Though it's assigning elements in setResults. I'm trying to pass the list in intent. but it's coming empty. what is wrong in the code?

Comment: it gives me correct size. even I get correct size inside setResult but somehow it's not assigning searchResults to searchedText.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put ArrayList in extras by `putExtra()` you have to use `putStringArrayListExtra()`. Try below code.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WordsFound.class);
 intent.putStringArrayListExtra("searchResults",searchedText);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It's not about putExtra or putStringArrayListExtra(). I'm getting empty searchedText even before passing in putExtra.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following code:

```
findViewById(R.id.btnSearch).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    for(String word: wordList){
      new DoWork(MainActivity.this).execute(word);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WordsFound.class);
    intent.putExtra("searchResults",searchedText);
    startActivity(intent);

  }
});
```

Let's dissect the code. No problem with the following code. It's the usual code for click listener:

findViewById(R.id.btnSearch).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
      }

Now, we look into the body code, from the following code:

```
for(String word: wordList){
  new DoWork(MainActivity.this).execute(word);
}
```

We knew that `DoWork` is an AsyncTask which is doing an **asynchronous** process. So, **the next code will be executed eventhough the DoWork haven't finished its process**.

Let's see the next code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WordsFound.class);
intent.putExtra("searchResults", searchedText);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here you put the extra from `searchedText` variable which is only initialized in onCreate with:

```
searchText = new ArrayList<String>();
```

So, you'll always have the empty list when setting the extra.

To overcome the empty list issue, you need to send the extra only after the `DoWork` is finished doing its job. You can try calling the Intent inside the `setResult`

Comment: Thanks for solution..!!

Comment: If this answer solve the problem, please mark this as accepted answer to close the question. :)